# Armazenamento de data do sistema

Tags: c, data

Preciso capturar a data do sistema e guardá-la numa variável inteira, pois precisarei compará-la com uma data que será informada pelo usuário. Encontrei a função `_strdate` que guarda a data no formado DD/MM/AA numa string, entretanto não é tão interessante no meu caso, porque pretendo que a data informada pelo usuário seja no formato DDMMAAAA. Existe alguma forma de capturar a data nesse formato e a converter para inteiro? Além disso, como eu posso fazer a comparação com uma outra data informada? Precisarei analisar número por número?

Answer (score 1):

Data é um negócio complicado. Na minha opinião você deveria armazenar como string e usar o formato AAAAMMDD, porque aí uma comparação de string serve para dizer se uma data é maior que outra. Se o usuário digita DDMMAAAA, não é difícil reordenar as partes.

Só aconselho usar inteiros para datas se você pretende armazenar o timestamp, como por exemplo o valor retornado pela função time(). Ela retorna o número de segundos desde 1/1/1970 0:00 GMT, então o momento "zero" correspondeu a 31/12/1969 21:00 no Brasil. A vantagem do timestamp é que ele vale no mundo todo (um fato com timestamp maior aconteceu depois de outro com timestamp menor, ainda que num lugar com fuso horário diferente).